# Assigning object after operation via operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I want to add contents of two classes and save them in another class. I have created constructor, parameterized constructor, destructor and overloaded `=` parameter. It is working fine for `Demo b = a;` but when I try to save the object given by `a.addition(b)`, there's error `no viable overloaded '='`. My concept is why the object is not getting copied to newly created object?

**Class Demo**

```
class Demo
{
    int* ptr;
public:
    Demo(int data = 0) {
        this->ptr = new int(data);
    }
    ~Demo(void) {
        delete this->ptr;
    }
    // Copy controctor
    Demo(Demo &x) {
        ptr = new int;
        *ptr = *(x.ptr);
    }
    void setData(int data) {
        *(this->ptr) = data;
    }
    int getData() {
        return *(this->ptr);
    }

    Demo operator = (Demo& obj) {
        Demo result;
        obj.setData(this->getData());
        return result;
    }

    Demo addition(Demo& d) {
        Demo result;
        cout << "result: " << &result << endl;
        int a = this->getData() + d.getData();

        result.setData(a);

        return result;
    }
};
```

**Main**

```
int main(void)
{
    Demo a(10);
    Demo b = a;
    Demo c;
    c = a.addition(b); // error here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your assignment operator is weird. It changes the *rhs* instead of the *lhs*. If I write `a = b` I do not expect b to be modified.

Comment: @StoryTeller You are right. That is by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator=` takes a referecne to non-const (i.e. `Demo&`) as its parameter, which can't bind to the temporary object returned by `addition`.

To solve the issue you should change the parameter type to reference to const (i.e. `const Demo&`), which could bind to temporary and is conventional.

BTW: The target and source of the assignment seem to be opposite. I suppose it should be implemented as

```
Demo& operator= (const Demo& obj) {
    setData(obj.getData());
    return *this;
}
```

And declare `getData` as a `const` member function.